# Sitecore: Get context item from rendering parameters

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I've a custom treelist field type that can resolve its datasource context item by following code.

```
Item contextItem = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.Items[ItemID];
Item queryItem = contextItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem(qs);
```

But a mishap happens when the context item is a rendering parameter. Because then the datasource context item is out of sitecore root. I could start my datasource query from sitecore root sure but its a multisite solution so, that won't be a good solution.

Is there any way I can resolve the context item (which is a page item in this case) from my custom treelist?

The solution is in sitecore 7.2.

Comment: The `id` of the context/parent item is passed through as a querystring parameter, you can check if this is set otherwise use the Context Item.

Comment: Context.Item would be the Field Editor which is from the core db. That won't be useful.

Comment: Sure, but the `id` of the item is passed through as a querystring parameters to the rendering parameters window, check the values passed in the Network tab in Chrome.